# Google Map Find Multiple NearBy User Location and Save

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am working on a ride sharing app.Currently It saves driver lat and lang periodically in mysql database. From available records it sends ride request to a single nearby Driver. Below is the code so far I have and it is saving trip request for a single nearest driver perfectly.Which I Need is to save trip request for multiple nearby drivers, so that who accepts first. Below is the code and any suggestion how can I acheive this

```
 //finding nearest driver
 $nearest_car = DriverLocation::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos(radians( longitude ) - radians('.$pickup_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$pickup_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'))
->having('distance', '<=', 5)->where('driver_location.status','Online')->where('driver_location.car_id',$car_id);
```

and saving the trip request for nearest driver

```
 $i=0;
if($i < count($nearest_car))
{
  $nearest_car = $nearest_car[$i];
  $driver_details = @User::where('id',$nearest_car->user_id)->first();
  //check the request are accepted or not
  $request_accepted=RideRequest::where('group_id',$driver_group_id)->where('status','Accepted')->get()->count();

  //some times request inserts duplicates so we check already insert or not for same rider id and driver id with this group
  $request_already=RideRequest::where('user_id',$rider_id)->where('driver_id',$nearest_car->user_id)->where('group_id',$driver_group_id)->get()->count();
  if(!$request_accepted)
  {
    if(!$request_already)
    {
      $last_second=RideRequest::where('driver_id',$nearest_car->user_id)->where('status','Pending')->get()->count();
      if(!$last_second)
      {
        $request  = new Request;
        $request->user_id          =   $rider_id;
        $request->group_id         =   null;
        $request->pickup_latitude  =   $pickup_latitude;
        $request->pickup_longitude =   $pickup_longitude;
        $request->drop_latitude    =   $drop_latitude;
        $request->drop_longitude   =   $drop_longitude;
        $request->driver_id        =   $nearest_car->user_id;
        $request->car_id           =   $car_id;
        $request->pickup_location  =   $pickup_location;
        $request->drop_location    =   $drop_location;
        $request->payment_mode   =   $payment_method_store;
        $request->status           =   'Pendings';
        $request->save();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the raw sql and take it from there. If that idea seems appealing, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, its lengthy work to change it again. can you suggest how can i achieve the same in above.I have tried with a for loop but it is inserting same driver id again and again.